# TRY CATCH in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, try-catch

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have tried to execute the following:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR'
END CATCH;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
>Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'TRY'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
```

Can any one tell me how execute try catch in SQL Server?

Comment: I do not get an error in SQL 2008

Comment: I am also able to run this code un-edited, SQL 2005.

Comment: Do you have anything else in the query window that may be executing as well?

Comment: Are you **really** on SQL Server 2008?? This error message "smells" like you're trying to use this on e.g. SQL Server 2000 that didn't have this feature yet....

Comment: @marc_s yes you are right. I was wrong with the version.Sorry to all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a completely valid statement for SQL Server 2005 and up, so I'd check your compatibility level using [sp_dbcmptlevel (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx):

```
exec sp_dbcmptlevel 'YourDatabaseName'
```

80 = SQL Server 2000
90 = SQL Server 2005
100 = SQL Server 2008

I think it will return 80 or lower, it seems that it doesn't know `BEGIN TRY`, only `BEGIN`.  The `BEGIN TRY` was added in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Jeeva Jsb, if you are sure about the compatibility mode, then create a new question and post your code

Comment: azure Dedicated SQL pool errors out with ...  Stored procedure sp_dbcmptlevel does not exist or is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have this error, the question becomes, have you put a BEGIN CATCH...END CATCH section in. If not, you get this error. If you have a BEGIN TRY...END TRY section with no T-SQL code in it, then it will also produce the error.

I don't think it's helpful people tell you that you're using SQL Server 2000. It is more likely a T-SQL coding issue as you tend to know what server you are running.

Answer (score 2):

```
Begin try
  Begin transaction
    --------
    --------
  Commit transaction
End try
Begin catch
  Rollback transaction
End catch
```

http://intquesans.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-we-can-use-try-catch-in-sql.html

Comment: In my case, I had put `Begin Transaction` before `Begin Try`, but `Commit Transaction` inside the `Try` block.  This answer showed me what I done wrong.